# docker user defined network

Tags: networking, docker, bridge

How come on a user defined network (driver:bridge) containers can not only communicate by IP address, but can also **resolve a container name to an IP address**, and on the default network (also driver:bridge) containers cannot resolve container name to ip?

On user defined network    `ping container_name` will work, meanwhile on default docker bridge only `ping 172.17.0.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because user defined networks contain an embedded DNS server that works differently from the one in the default network.

For details, see the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) on this.